# WebSockets served by a Servlet Container

Tags: java, servlets, websocket

I was taking a look at WebSockets last week and made a few thoughts on how to implement the server side with the Java Servlet API. I didn't spend too much time, but ran into the following problems during a few tests with Tomcat, which seem impossible to solve without patching the container or at least making container specific modifications to the HttpServletResponse implementation:

- The WebSocket specification mandate a defined message in the 101 HTTP response. HttpServletResponse.setStatus(int code, String message) is deprecated without mentioning a usable replacement. After changing the default Tomcat configuration, I made Tomcat honor my message string, but since the method is deprecated, I'm not sure if this will work with other servlet containers.
- The WebSocket specification require a specified order of the first few headers in the HTTP response to the connection upgrade request. The servlet API does not offer a method to specify the order of the response headers and Tomcat adds its own headers to the response, placing a few of them before any headers, which are added by the servlet implementation.
- Since the content length of the response is not known when committing the header, Tomcat automatically switches to chunked transfer encoding for the response, which is incompatible with the WebSocket specification.

Am I missing something obvious, or is it really not possible to integrate WebSocket server endpoints in a servlet based web app?

Comment: I ran into pretty much the same issues.  I really wanted to extend Tomcat, to show how I would like a "WebSocket Servlet" to look like, when its added to the Java EE specs.  To see how I hacked Tomcat, you can look at the patches at http://java.dzone.com/articles/tomcat-websockets-html5

Answer (score 8):

There is an implementation in [Jetty](http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/jetty_websocket_server). We can hope that tomcat and jetty find a compatible API.

Comment: I know, but I was more or less hoping that WebSocket support should be possible using the standard Servlet API and not by using any container specific extensions.

Comment: I understand. Then only the coming Servlet 3.0 spec is a solution. Currently the spec is a beta (I think). But there are already some implementations of the spec. Of course in beta.

Answer (score 6):

The [Glassfish Atmosphere](http://atmosphere.java.net/) project will do what you want. There is a servlet you can define to do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

`jWebSocket` claims to run as a Tomcat application.  Unfortunately some files are missing in the binary distribution of `jWebSocket`.  Some people are trying to recompile `jWebSocket` and get the necessary files, since the source code is available.  All in all, `jWebSocket` does not seem as a reliable product.

Comment: i am having the same experience

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is a very good one (open source and completely free): http://www.jWebSocket.org

Comment: No, jWebSocket is not servlet based.