# How to send push notifications from a Java Servlet for web application?

Tags: java, servlets, web

In my application I have to show a notification on a particular action taken place?

I have to show logged in user a notification then.

One way to get notifications is to keep polling after certain time interval. that is pull notification. But this causes unnecessary hits to server.

How can I use push notifications from server?
I am using Java Servlets and JSP with Tomcat.

Comment: Take a look at WebSockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190500/websockets-served-by-a-servlet-container

Comment: You can take a look at HTML5 SSE (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp )
Not sure if this will solve your problem. It's basically polling, but you don't need to do it. The browser does it.

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays a promising way of client-server communication is to use Websockets.

See [What are Long-Polling, Websockets, Server-Sent Events (SSE) and Comet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet) to see some other ways together with the Websockets and for an advantages of Websockets with an introduction see [An Introduction To WebSockets](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebSockets for this purpose. There are multiple implementations available like [jwebsocket](http://jwebsocket.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Comet](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-asynchhttp.html) model and [Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Servlet3.0 Async functionality.

Here is an Chat example which does push : [Servlet 3.0 Async Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960916/servlet-3-async-task-on-tomcat-7/7966989#7966989)