# how to put a listener on URL (website)

Tags: java, apache, web, arduino, guava

I know java.nio.file package provides a file change notification API (Watch Service API).

I need similar kind of service for getting notifications anytime a website is changed.
Besides polling  or some api  built on top of polling, is there  a library/API available?
If no, how can I do better than periodic polling (or alternative)?
If I am forced to do polling (because there are no alternatives), is there some tag in http/html message that tells me when the website was last modified so that i can detect the change without parsing entire website content and comparing with last read for detecting modification changes

Comment: There's http headers for last-modified and whatnot, but the only way you'll GET those headers is by polling the web site. Some sites may offer a "push" version to notify of changes (e.g. like SO does for updates/messages), but that's a per-site thing, and not in any way "standard".

Comment: @March..thanks for http headers. I am reading from internal website. How would I make this website to push changes to my java code (or to any external party outside website)

Comment: comet/longpolling is one way, websockets are getting "bigger" and more standard.

Comment: thanks @Marc for sharing the terminology for what I am looking!! Here are some relevant links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010701/how-push-notification-java-servlet-for-web-application  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet?lq=1

Comment: WebSockets can help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377384/why-use-ajax-when-websockets-is-available. You can also use MQTT protocol over the web sockets.

Comment: the website I am trying to download sits on embedded device (Arduino based).  I can not put big software stack on it. So far I have only webserver and AJAX on the device. However these were good suggestions/hints that I should educate myself

Comment: You should also look into the HTTP HEAD method, which (IIRC) doesn't return any content, but only the headers associated with a request. This may enable you to read the the last-modified header without having to download the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I came across cwebsockets, websocket implementation for Arduino platform

https://code.google.com/p/cwebsocket/